# Seaborn Boxplot with jittered outliers

Tags: python, seaborn

I want a Boxplot with jittered outliers. But only the outliers not the non-outliers.
Searching the web you often find a workaround combining `sns.boxplot()` and `sns.swarmplot()`.

[image]

The problem with that figure is that the outliers are drawn twice. I don't need the red ones I only need the jittered (green) ones.

Also the none-outliers are drawn. I don't need them also.

I also have a [feautre request at upstream open](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3148) about it. But on my current research there is no Seaborn-inbuild solution for that.

This is an MWE reproducing the boxplot shown.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import pandas
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_theme()

random.seed(0)

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Vals': random.choices(range(200), k=200)})
df_outliers = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Vals': random.choices(range(400, 700), k=20)})

df = pandas.concat([df, df_outliers], axis=0)

flierprops = {
    'marker': 'o',
    'markeredgecolor': 'red',
    'markerfacecolor': 'none'
}

# Usual boxplot
ax = sns.boxplot(y='Vals', data=df, flierprops=flierprops)

# Add jitter with the swarmplot function
ax = sns.swarmplot(y='Vals', data=df, linewidth=.75, color='none', edgecolor='green')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach to have jittered outliers. The jitter is similar to `sns.stripplot()`, not to `sns.swarmplot()` which uses a rather elaborate spreading algorithm.  Basically, all the "line" objects of the subplot are checked whether they have a marker. The x-positions of the "lines" with a marker are moved a bit to create jitter.  You might want to vary the amount of jitter, e.g. when you are working with `hue`.

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme()

random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'Vals': random.choices(range(200), k=200)})
df_outliers = pd.DataFrame({
     'Vals': random.choices(range(400, 700), k=20)})

df = pd.concat([df, df_outliers], axis=0)

flierprops = {
     'marker': 'o',
     'markeredgecolor': 'red',
     'markerfacecolor': 'none'
}

# Usual boxplot
ax = sns.boxplot(y='Vals', data=df, flierprops=flierprops)

for l in ax.lines:
     if l.get_marker() != '':
          xs = l.get_xdata()
          xs += np.random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2, len(xs))
          l.set_xdata(xs)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot with jittered outliers]

An alternative approach could be to filter out the outliers, and then call `sns.swarmplot()` or `sns.stripplot()` only with those points.  As seaborn doesn't return the values calculated to position the whiskers, you might need to calculate those again via scipy, taking into account seaborn's filtering on x and on hue.